# using powershell to compare TFS and SQL server DB Scheme

Tags: sql-server, powershell, tfs

We have our database scheme in TFS.  I was wondering if it was possible to write a PowerShell script that compared the actual Database scheme in our production database to the scheme in TFS and commit any changes  to TFS between the two.  I have seen some really nice PowerShell scripts comparing two DB's but was unsure about TFS and the DB?

Comment: Have you looked at vidualy studio sql database compare and sql data compare?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd193250(v=vs.100).aspx we use this in our tfs build and deployments. You ciuld wrap it up in powershell maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have loose SQL files for creating your database then you will need an instance. If however, you are using a Redgate, ReadyRoll, or VS Database project then you can use their respective tools.

For VS Database you get an output of a DACPAC and you can compair: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210546.aspx

This is all based on a built version of your project. You should be comparing the output of your build with the database. Not the source.